# Main character is transmigrated to cultivation world with a system. After becoming strong he comes back to Earth to save his sister at her university

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

In this manhua the main character becomes stronger by stronger everyday with help of the system, then he breaks the formation  to travel back earth with his girlfriend and he saves his father and his sister when she kidnapped in a university.

Also in another world he creates his car and wepons and also he creates his own satellite and phone then he call his friends from another world(earth).MC girlfriend always flies on the sword.

Also the heroine has a flower tattoo on her forehead.Please help me to find this manhua name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: When you say he transforms his car into bumblebee, do you mean the [Transformer](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81mO3LX+onL._AC_SX425_.jpg)?

Comment: What did the tattoo look like? Some options here; https://www.reddit.com/r/Manhua/comments/pnyvcd/is_there_any_significant_meanings_for_the_symbols/

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the main character and/or the heroine?

Answer (score 1):

*[The Ultimate Scheming System](https://www.webnovel.com/comic/the-ultimate-scheming-system_12272676305179201)*, or *Zui Qiang Fan Taolu Xitong* might be the story you are looking for.

[image: Title image for The Ultimate Scheming System]

> I backhand giving you a scheme, sweeping the invincible hand in the immortal world, just ask is there anyone else? Fronting is like the wind; always by my side! The front road is long; and only fronting may be my friend! Life and death are bearish; !
> "Young people, when I started the routine, you are still wearing open pants!"
> Xu Que is on the road of scheming, not every day, or on the way to the scheme!

A somewhat better summary can be found [here](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/t0xz54f/zui-qiang-fan-taolu-xitong).

> Scamming all day, every day, often venturing alone. He bluffs to get the ultimate power in this cultivation world?! world traveler Xue Que doesn’t always bluff, but he needs to.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edits. I wanted to add more details and, in general, site policy has been bearish on linking to sites with unauthorized use of copyrighted works, with manga "scanlation" sites being particularly targeted. Incidentally, the girl he first meets does indeed fly on her sword in the first chapter, although the only flower I saw was the one used as Scenery Censor for her "flower" when she nearly pees on the protagonist.

Comment: no your ok man i understand just giving a answer without any explanation would make anyone confused